# Anybody know of any secret sources to get from YYZ to CDG for July for under $700?

Tags: tickets, paris, toronto

I need to book a last minute ticket departing on July 1 2015 from Toronto to Paris. Are there any "secret" sources or other "ways" to get a ticket for less than $700 CDN?

Comment: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/how-does-email-communication-with-a-private-pilot-affect-faa-rules-on-compensati might give you some ideas

Comment: @verve, reopen voted

Comment: @Gayot Fow It might be the lack of sleep talking but are you saying I should hang out with pilots?

Comment: Departing Toronto to Paris on July 1. Possibly returning the end of the month but oneway is good too.

Comment: Does it have to be Paris? The more flexible you are (eg something in Western Europe with cheap onward flights), the more hope you have!

Comment: Expedia is giving $759 one way. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Gagravarr I actually always find a place to stay AND then book the ticket. Lol.  I found a cheap space in Paris so that's the only reason I want to go.

Comment: @verve If you're willing to book (for the sake of an argument) YYZ to DUB as one flight, then DUB to Paris as a second (likely on a LCC), it could turn out to be cheaper. Flight to Barcelona then TGV to Paris is another. Hence the query - do you have to fly to Paris, or are you flexible as long as you get to Paris eventually?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm flexible as long I don't need a Visa to go through another space or something. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/).

Skyscanner searches a vast array of airlines and air travel websites, to obtain the lowest fares publicly available.

For your proposed one-way trip leaving Toronto on July 1 and going to Paris, it comes up with [$585 on Condor](http://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/yyz/cdg/150701/airfares-from-toronto-pearson-international-to-paris-charles-de-gaulle-in-july-2015.html?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false) ($713 CAD at today's exchange rate) as the cheapest flight, YYZ-FRA-CDG. If you leave late the previous night instead, you can get a [nonstop flight for <s>$590</s> $629](http://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/yyz/cdg/150630/airfares-from-toronto-pearson-international-to-paris-charles-de-gaulle-in-june-2015.html?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false) (you were too slow and missed it).

I think you will find it quite difficult to do better than that.